# Como visualizar dois arquivos lado a lado no Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

É possível visualizar dois arquivos lado a lado no Notepad++?

Por exemplo, no vim, o comando `:split` faz isso.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clique com o botão direito em uma aba, e então selecione *Mover para outra tela* (*Move to Other view*).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ótima dica, parabéns por multiplicar o seu conhecimento.